# Mongo DB Aggregation using match and group aggregate function

Tags: json, mongodb

I'm looking to aggregate the sum of "paid_amount" by "user_id", "real_currency_spend", and "paid_currency".

The idea is to get totals by user by currency type (to avoid counting Yen "paid_amount" with USD,GBP, etc.

The current code:

```
{$match: {"paid_currency_type": "real_currency",  "paid_amount": {$gt: 0}}}
{$group: {_id:"$user_id", total: {$sum : "$paid_amount"}}}
```

The current output:

```
_id: 1121749754875670248    
total: #.##
```

The desired output:

```
_id: ##### (equal to user_id)
USD: #.##
Yen: #.##
Cur: #.##
```

With each currency type from real_currency_name making up the field name and the total per user in the collection making up the field value.

I ideally do not want to use `$push` to put the currencies into an array format per id, but if it must be done... it must be done.

Comment: Could you provide example documents?

Comment: I ended up with something quite close this morning when trying this again:{ $group: { _id: "$paid_currency_name", total: { $sum: "$paid_amount" }}}

Answer (score 0):

I am new to MongoDB, but I would go for the [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)  and use conditional sentences(please note code not checked, just a "hint"):

```
{$match: {"paid_currency_type": "real_currency",  "paid_amount": {$gt: 0}}}
{$group: {_id:"$user_id", curr: 'real_currency', total: {$sum : 'paid_amount'}}
{$project: {_id:'$_id',USD:{{$cond: [{$eq:{'$curr', 'USD']}, '$total', $multiply[$total,$change.usd.real_currency]}},
                       Yen:{ you know what I mean ;-)},
                       Cur:{}}}
```

Please note I used an external object $change, which would be containing the changing rate to the currencies. I am new to MongoDB, so I do not know exactly how to add an external variable in your aggregation (maybe is just using them like I did, but not sure, sorry).

If you are running your aggregation for each currency, it should be easier, forget the conditonal operator I wrote and just get the $project idea and show the three currencies (one from data , the other with $multiply for the changing rate).

Hope this helps!